# WebSphere 7: WebServiceException: Error: Maintain Session is enabled but none of the session properties (Cookies, Over-written URL) are returned

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, websphere-7

What's the reason for the following error in WebSphere 7.0 and Java 6?

```
Error: Maintain Session is enabled but none of the session properties
(Cookies, Over-written URL) are returned for web service program when
SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY set to true on client side.
```

Comment: In the future, please at least _attempt_ to Google your error before posting a question :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the info from [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK72991):

**Error description**

When using WebSphere Application Server and Feature Pack for
Webservices the following exception is encountered when using
a service to make calls to the server after creating and
configuring the web service proxies.

The first service call always should create a new HTTP session;
the second call needs to use the session from the first one.

The problem is that during the second call the server no longer
returns the session cookie. The client proxy then returns

```
[03.09.08 13:49:31:892 CEST] 0000000a ExceptionFact 1
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory
createWebServiceException Create
Exception:

javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error: Maintain Session is enabled but none of the session properties (Cookies, Over-written URL) are returned.
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:178)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException( ExceptionFactory.java:79)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:125)
at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.BindingProvider.setupSessionContext(BindingProvider.java:172)
```

**Problem summary**

```
****************************************************************
* USERS AFFECTED:  All users of WebSphere Application Server   *
*                  Feature Pack for JAX-WS Web Services that   *
*                  use cookies.                                *
****************************************************************
* PROBLEM DESCRIPTION: JAX-WS does not allow session cookie    *
*                      sharing between client                  *
*                      BindingProvider instances for           *
*                      synchronous proxy invocations           *
****************************************************************
* RECOMMENDATION:                                              *
****************************************************************
JAX-WS does not allow session sharing between the client
BindingProvider instances for synchronous proxy invocations.
JAX-RPC did allow session cookie sharing between clients.
```

**Problem conclusion**

The JAX-WS synchronous proxy code was corrected and now
supports session sharing between client BindingProvider
instances.

JAX-WS allows client applications to copy session cookies from
one BindingProvider's request context and put it on another
BindingProvider instance's request context to effectively
share a session.

The fix for this APAR is currently targeted for inclusion in
fixpack 6.1.0.25 and 7.0.0.1.  Please refer to the Recommended
Updates page for delivery information:
http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27004980